# Showing $A \subseteq B$ with inequalities.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $z_0 \in \Bbb R^n$ and $r_0 \in \Bbb R^+$ be arbitrary.

Show that there exist $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R^n$ and $r_1, r_2 \in \Bbb R^+$ such that $A=B,$ where:

$A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n: |z_0-(x + y)| \lt r_0 \}$ $B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n : |x_1-x|\lt r_1 \text{ and } |x_2-y| \lt r_2\}$,

I can show $B \subseteq A$, but I'm having trouble finding a way to show $A \subseteq B$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what is $z_0$?.

Comment: And what is $r_0$?

Comment: Added the specific conditions in for everything.

Comment: I think we are asking their relationship with your x1, r_1 etc, otherwise, how could the two sets be equal ?

Comment: @YujieZha I added in their relationships, everything should be apparent now.

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan From the way the question is currently phrased, I think it's clear even if it could be expressed a bit more efficiently. The point is to show that for every $z_0\in\mathbb R^n$ and every $r_0>0,$ there exist $x_1,x_2,r_1,r_2$ for which the two sets are equal. $\qquad$

Comment: @YujieZha : See above. $\uparrow \qquad$

Comment: @OliverG you need to be more specific, e.g. I guess you might mean $z_0 = (x_1,x_2)$ or close (specify how close then). Otherwise if $z_0= (0,0), x_1= 1000, x_2=10000$?

Comment: @YujieZha I've updated the question previously to include that $z_0$ is an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: @MichaelHardy nice rephrase, it's clear now!

Comment: @OliverG I suggest you update your question using the rephrase of Michael's comment, as that's what you want to ask.

Comment: @YujieZha I have re-phrased the question so as to be explicit in words what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sets are never equal, because $B$ is bounded, but $A$ is not. For example, for any vector $v\ne 0$ we have
$(x(t),y(t))=(z_0,0)+t(v,-v)\in A$ for each $t\in\Bbb R$, but $(x(t),y(t))\not\in B$ for large enough $t$ for any choice of $x_1,x_2,r_1,r_2$.

Comment: How is $A$ unbounded?  It's a set of points that are within an open ball of finite radius?  If $z_0$ is an arbitrary point, then it's the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $|z_0 - (x+y)| \lt r_0$, isn't this bounded?

Comment: @OliverG $x+y$ is bounded, but not $x$, $y$ separately. For example, for $z_0=0$ and $r_0=1$ it looks like [an infinite strip](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Cx%2By%7C%3C1).